# Splitting a double into an array in C

Tags: c

I'd like the following code to work:

```
double num = 31415; /* num will never have a decimal part */
/* ... code here so that we can now say */
printf("%d", num_array[0] == 3 && num_array[1] == 1 && num_array[4] == 5); //1
```

I realize it's trivial to do this with ints (just `int i=0; while(num>0) numarr[size-++i] = num%10, num/=10;` where size is predetermined to be the number of digits in the number), but that obviously won't work for floats/doubles because you can't mod one floats.

And yes, I need to use floats/doubles, despite not using the floating point section (it's an exercise).

And I have figured out how to determine the number of digits in a double, using floor().

```
/* n > 0, n=floor(n) */
int numdigits(double n){
    int i = 0;
    while (n >0)
        n = floor(n/10), i++;
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look up `fmod`. The number of digits will probably be easier to compute using `log10`.

Comment: +1 for the log10() suggestion.  `int digits = (int)log10(n) + 1;`

Answer (score 2):

It's probably easiest to just convert it to a string:

```
char* str = malloc(num_digits+1);
snprintf(str, num_digits+1, "%f", num);
```

Indexing into `str` will give you each digit as an ASCII value, so you'll need to subtract `'0'` to get the actual numeric value:

```
str[0] - '0' == 3;
str[1] - '0' == 1;
str[2] - '0' == 4;
...
```

Comment: I wanted to see if I could do it without strings :), but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from fmod(), you could also cast to a int64_t or long long int, and use % as before.  If the range is less than 10 digits, you could use a int32_t.